# What is the HTTP method PURGE?

Tags: http, http-method

Today when using Postman I noticed the method option of `PURGE`. I have never encountered it in practice and cannot find the explanation of it's purpose.

What is this method used for, where did it come from, and is there a spec for it somewhere?

Comment: @nos: there *IS* an HTTP `PURGE` verb, it is just not defined in the HTTP RFCs. Some HTTP servers and caching systems, such as Squid and Varnish, actually do implement `PURGE` (see [this](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/purging.html)), and even curl supports sending `PURGE` requests (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119786/varnish-purge-using-http-and-regex)).

Comment: @nos I removed the link to ietf to prevent distraction. I'm curious what this verb's business is in HTTP, that is the point of the question. If there is no spec, how did it come about. I'm looking for some kind of explanation as to why this verb is somewhat popular, but not popular enough to be specified. Seems odd and random to me, I don't understand what it is supposed to offer in an API when beside GET/POST/PUT/DELETE etc.

Comment: Being crude: POST = append, PUT = put, DELETE = dereference, PURGE = ?

Comment: @RemyLebeau irrelevant - Curl supports sending *any* syntactically valid HTTP method name

Comment: @RemyLebeau, if you post your comment here as an answer I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Also, they aren't verbs, they are methods. e.g. head & options are not verbs anyways.

Comment: RFC2616 (HTTP/1.1) "method" = 164 results "verb" = 2 results, and those are for 'verbally' and 'verbose'. https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt

Comment: @ElijahLynn yeah, I can't find any usages in RFCs of "verb". If you would like the points, you should suggest an edit for your catch.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There is an HTTP `PURGE` method, though it is not defined in the HTTP RFCs (which do allow for custom methods beyond the standard defined methods). Some HTTP servers and caching systems actually do implement `PURGE`, for instance Squid and Varnish:

Squid: [How can I purge an object from my cache?](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/OperatingSquid#How_can_I_purge_an_object_from_my_cache.3F)

Varnish: [Purging and banning](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/purging.html)

And it is possible to send `PURGE` requests with curl, for example:

[Varnish purge using HTTP and REGEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119786/varnish-purge-using-http-and-regex)

Comment: Is there "HTTP" that is not HTTP but is HTTP? If not the RFCs, what defines what is and what isn't HTTP?

Comment: The official HTTP specs, RFC 2616 and RFCs 7230-7235, define 8 standard methods, and also allow for custom methods as well: `Method = "OPTIONS" | "GET" | "HEAD" | "POST" | "PUT" | "DELETE" | "TRACE" | "CONNECT" | extension-method`.  Custom methods are supposed to be registered with [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml), but `PURGE` is not registered.

Comment: Could you also tell me if it's idempotent? Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35632607/is-the-http-verb-purge-idempotent

Comment: As it's not defined by an RFC, I don't think there can a definitive answer to whether it's idempotent. It will depend on how the specific product / server that you're using it with (e.g. Varnish) chooses to handle it.

Comment: Nginx also uses it for purging content from the cache.

Answer (score -3):

I use the PURGE method if I need to clear the cach in varnish (at the apache level, before php)

wget --method=PURGE --header "x-purge-token: xxx" -H -S [www.excepted.com/a/b/c.html](http://www.excepted.com/a/b/c.html)

If you look head response this info is cache

```
  age: 656
  x-cache: HIT|MISS
  x-cv: ftp.server.com
```